# Preprocessor #if directive

Tags: c, if-statement

I am writing a big code and I don't want it all to be in my main.c so I wrote a .inc file that has IF-ELSE statement with function and I was wondering can it be written like this:

```
#if var==1
process(int a)
{
    printf("Result is: %d",2*a);
}
#else
process(int a)
{
    printf("Result is: %d",10*a);
}
#endif
```

I tried to compile it but it gives me errors or in best case it just goes on the first function *process* without checking the var variable (it is set to 0).

Comment: What error(s) are you getting ?

Comment: "gives me errors" Show them. And how do you set var? `#define var 0`?

Comment: Do you want to only include one of the methods at compile time? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Bart I'm working in NetBeans with cygwin c-compiler and there it shows me no errors and starts from first function but when compiled in MS Visual Studio 2010 it says :"error c3861: 'process':identifier not found" (and only one function is Active Preprocessor Block and one isn't)
I defined var in my main.c as global variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preprocessor doesn't "know" the value of any variable, because it does its work even before compilation, not at runtime.

In the condition of a preprocessor `#if` you can only evaluate `#define`'d symbols and constant expressions.

The particular example you are showing can be simply converted to:

```
printf("Result is: %d", (var == 1 ? 2: 10) * a);
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion with #define'd variables.
The example you showed me is correct but this is only the simple function. I have lots and lots of definitions, functions, etc., so I thought the easiest way to separate them is with #if-else.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete. For a standard conforming compiler your code would always be correct. In `#if` expression evaluations all identifiers that are not known to the preprocessor are simply replaced with `0` (or false if you want). So in your particular case, if `var` is just a variable and not a macro, the result would always be the second version of your function.

For the error that you report for MS: I did know that the MS compilers aren't standard conforming, but I wasn't aware that they don't even fulfill such basic language requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
process(int a)
{
   if (var == 1)
      printf("Result is: %d",2*a);
   else
      printf("Result is: %d",10*a);
}
```

It is important to remember that the preprocessor is its own *program* and not a part of the program you are writing.  The variable "var" (or whatever var represents here) is not in the the namespace of the preprocessor's identifiers.